# Strictifying nullable fields for validation

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, nullable, non-nullable, typescript-types

I'm trying to get the compiler to help me with validation of payloads received over the network. So what I want to do is take a JSON payload over the wire and make sure the compiler complains if all the fields are not set. I know the way to do this is to use validation functions but even before I get to the validation part I need to generate some boilerplate that converts a type with nullable fields into a type with strict fields. So the validation functions must have the following signature

```
type Validator<T> = (i: T) => Strictify<T>;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get `Strictify` to actually work. When I write the following it doesn't work

```
type Strictify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined>
};
type Test = { k?: string };
type StrictTest = Strictify<Test>;
```

The type of `StrictTest` should be `{ k: string }` but it's actually still `{ k?: string }`. The interesting part is if I change the definition of `Test` to `{ k: string | undefined }` then it works. The strictified type is what I expect it to be. Anyone know how to make this all work without expanding every `k?: T` to `k: T | undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version would work if the field type were to have been declared as `string|undefined`. Although under `strictNullChecks` optional fields are shown as having the type `string|undefined` they are not the same thing, optionality is a property of the field.

To remove the optional modifier from the field when using a homomorphic mapped type, starting in typescript 2.8, you can add `-?` to the type:

```
type Strictify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined>
};
type Test = { k?: string };
type StrictTest = Strictify<Test>;
```

Comment: Oh nice. By the way is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @davidk01 The PR is the best place to read about it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21919

Comment: Cool. Much appreciated.